# How to add a button to the Asana task pane

Tags: api, greasemonkey, userscripts, asana

I've noticed that several "featured" Asana apps are integrated into the task pane (just search for "pane" in the [app page](https://asana.com/apps).) For example, here's the Harvest button, once you enable their "app":

[image: Harvest button in Asana task pane]

I'd like to do the same for my own extension. Is there a documented way to do this? Or should I put my Reverse Engineer hat on and code the thing in Greasemonkey?

Answer (score 1):

Harvest is an official integration - we have an API for integrating public apps, but nothing we officially support for integrating into the UI. I'm not saying it's categorically *impossible*, but we certainly don't officially support this. Depending on what you want to do, Greasemonkey might be feasible for personal purposes, but we'd probably discourage customers from installing hacks like this. One misbehaving extension can destroy a *lot* of work - not just out of malice, but by accident, especially if something in our UI changes and the assumptions the Greasemonkey script made no longer applies.

In general, we'd love to provide hooks into Asana for third-party developers in future, but it's probably a long ways off. Can I ask what you're looking to provide? It may help inform our thinking for our roadmap.

Comment: Our company needs this type of integration (or extension) as well.  It's about 2 year, is there some progress in paradigm ? Or are we forced to use harvest?